# What is Apocalypse wearing?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

In the movie, we can see that Apocalypse is wearing some kind of suit

> that, alongside his own self, his four principal followers protect with their lives even as the ancient Egyptians betrayed them and their doom is nigh. Besides protecting his life, they also made sure that the entire suit is transferred to his new body.

It seems this suit is regarded with equal importance to his life. What is this suit, and why is it so important? What is it made of, such that Magneto - for all the metal on Earth and the adamantium in Wolverine - can't control Apocalypse's suit?

Comment: The armor is Celestial technology. It's probably safe to say it's made more out of magic than metal. Even powerful Asgardian weapons have trouble penetrating it. The Celestials stop by Earth every 6000 years or so to monitor human evolution and also direct it through genetic experimentation. This is in fact the origin of mutant kind. I doubt the movies are allowed to touch on this at all though, since Marvel owns cinematic rights to the Celestials.

Comment: Regarding his suit being transferred to his new body, I don't think that would have been so urgent under normal circumstances - it's just that a suit of armor is something that may help a bit when many tons of rock are collapsing on top of oneself.

Comment: The title part of the question just sounds like the intro to a saucy phone conversation.

Answer (score 11):

#### While *X-men: Apocalypse* does not reveal the origin of the armor Apocalypse wears, it is presumed to be the same exotic device worn by the comic version of the character. The suit is a device created by the [Celestials](http://marvel.com/universe/Celestials). It has no official name or designation and has been dubbed the ["Apocalypse Armor"](http://xmenrebirth.wikia.com/wiki/Apocalypse_Armor).

According to an **[interview with CBR](http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=article&id=40927)**, Rick Remender, writer of "Uncanny X-Force" reveals the origin of the Apocalypse armor and its unique pedigree: the armor was created by the Celestials who provided it to "evolutionary caretakers" of emergent species and enhanced the power of their wearers.

> **Remender:** I planned out the armor that Phil designed and Evan wears. The armors aren't like, "Hey here's some armor." These are Celestial-made armors that enhance and give whoever is Apocalypse a lot of power. You'll be seeing that armor in some flashbacks maybe during Egyptian times. That armor is going to play a historical role as well. The Brotherhood unearthed it and brought it in to give to [Evan](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Evan_Sabahnur_(Earth-616)). It was a young Apocalypse's armor.

[image: Image of Evan Sabahnur wearing Apocalypse's armor]

> **Interviewer:** So, the armor is almost Apocalypse's symbol of the authority bestowed upon him by the Celestials?
>
> **Remender:** I've worked all this out. We're going to be seeing a lot of the mythology of Apocalypse carry on into "Uncanny Avengers" moving forward. It's not quite a blood line. Apocalypse was the first mutant and thus was chosen by the Celestials to protect and care for the other mutants and to make sure that the humans didn't wipe them out before they had an opportunity to flourish. That was his cosmically granted charge.

As a result of this unique cosmic origin, it is likely the armor is resistant to Magneto's power, no matter how much it may resemble metal, it is probably some unique composition making it extremely durable and resistant to physical and energy attacks. In the comics, he boasts that Thor's *Jarnbjorn* (his enchanted axe) cannot harm his armor.

[image: Image with Thor strike Apocalypse full on the chest with Jarnbjorn, apparently with no effect]

Thus any time we see Apocalypse in his armor, and it resembles this particular shape, it is likely the same Celestial-designed armor. The design above is a variation of the original design which also had extensive cables which connected the back of the armor to Apocalypse body and extended to the back of his hands/gloves.

If you look at the movie version you can see the cables on his upper arms, held close to the body (instead of hanging free which might have been difficult to deal with in terms of filming and costuming) so they still are part of the design, however different from the original costume designs from the comics.

**As to the cables and why they exist:** No answer has ever been definitively given. Given their creation by the Celestials, they could have no discernible purpose to Human science.

- Apocalypse's armor gives his already powerful mutation, even greater range and facility.
- He can transform his flesh and the armor into whatever he wants them to be, including wings, tentacles, rockets or blasters. There doesn't appear to be any limits to their ability to transform.

[image: Image of Apocalypse from X-Men: Apocalypse]

Answer (score 1):

Apocalypse armor is **not** metal. In fact it's not even material of thus planet nor world. It is called **Celestial Armor** and it doesn't come off. You don't put it on, take it off, or even "wear it".

En Sabah Nur; "*Apocalypse's birth name" which also means "Morning Light" in Arabic*, mixed his blood with the armor. That's the only way to harness the power of that armor for yourself. Again, you don't just put it on ..you become one with it.

Celestial Armor: what is Celestial?
Well that's pretty simple. A Celestial is another word for god. Celestial's are actually a race of beings. They're a group of very large sized gods. If you've seen Galactus, that's what they are like.  They are extremely large in size, have a very huge ego and self importance.  Galactus has a humanoid face while the Celestial are more robot looking.

Apocalypse is basically wearing "*or became one with God Armor*" by mixing his blood with it. That's why manipulating metal isn't gonna work by Magneto. Kinda like the Juggernaut, his armor is not metal.  It's metal "like" but isn't metal: it's magic. Juggernaut got his power and armor by touching a demonic rock that has become one with him.  The man in the Juggernaut armor agreed with the demon to share his body together in exchange for the power that comes with it.

Magneto won't be able to do anything to him.