# What are the tubes on apocalypses head for?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse, marvel

Dont know how to describe this better, but what are the two tubes on every side of apocalypse head? Are they part of his armor? Or part of his body? What is the usage of them? Does he also have them in the comics?

[image]

Maybe related to this question [What is Apocalypse wearing?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129479/what-is-apocalypse-wearing), but I am asking specific about the tubes only.

Comment: Probably an *ancient* fashion statement thingy. I'm sure chicks of his time, loved that. :)

Answer (score 2):

They are part of his armor and don't have a stated purpose. The armor we see in variations of the armor in comics do have tubes, not from head to neck, but in other places so from a creative stand point it is likely just a way to incorporate more of the comic look into the movie look that don't get in the way and makes sense.

As to what purpose they serve or could serve? If you pressed the creators say what they are for they'd probably say something like connecting his thoughts to the armor so that he can control it or something that it does without having to press a button. It could also just be a small bit of neck protection, but this is doubtful.